# Delay application startup till sidecar (hashicorp Vault) is up in Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, health-check, kubernetes-health-check

I am looking for a way where we can start the (NodeJs) app server (i.e. delay it) only after vault agent is up. One way I can think, is to check the availability of the agent (by connecting to 8200) in the readiness probe so that the app server declares itself up only when Agent is up.

I am wondering if there is a "Depends On Container/Sidecar" feature in Helm/Yaml or we need to only do it programmatically in the handler of readiness probe.

Without this this the app server may start accepting request even before vault agent is ready in the sidecar container.

Comment: Which version of `helm` is used? Also `readiness probe` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Hi. I didn't find any other suggestion but looks like readiness probe is the right thing to do. One thing I observed after successful startup if vault goes down intermittently (though the agent is up), the pod also getting marked as Not Ready